# PostLoad method is not being called on an Id class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity class and another class is Identity class of this entity.
I have written @javax.persistence.PostLoad annotation in Id class to put some default value on one of the column.

But I found out that it is not being called at all. Is it that ID classes should not have this annotation?

Comment: could you please put your code here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can annotate a method in you **Entity** class by @PostLoad to set default value to ...

if you annotate you ID class, then you need to introduce it as Callback Listener in your Entity class :

```
@EntityListeners({ID.class})
class MyEntity
```

and i don't think its a good idea, because the instance of your Listener is not related to the Instance of ID in your Entity class.  they are 2 different object of ID class.

@PostLoad

> Is used to specify callback methods
>   for the corresponding lifecycle event.
>   This annotation may be applied to
>   methods of an entity class, a mapped
>   superclass, or a callback listener
>   class.

Comment: Thank you mohammad. My mistake, just I am about to post the same. It was resolved by moving the @PostLoad to the Entity class instead of identity class.